# How to specify only the element being clicked in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to only trigger the function on the button being click - currently my code is applying it to all elements and only the first is changing innerTEXT

```js
var toggleInnerHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleBtn");
  var desc = document.querySelectorAll('.description');
  

        for (i = 0; i < toggleInnerHTML.length; i++) {
          toggleInnerHTML[i].addEventListener('click', toggleText);
          var curText = toggleInnerHTML[i].innerText;
        }
       
        function toggleText() {
          for (i = 0; i < curText.length; i++) {
            if(this.innerText == curText[i]){
              toggleInnerHTML[i].innerText = "-";
            }
            else{
              toggleInnerHTML[i].innerText = curText[i];
            }
          }
            for (i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
              desc[i].classList.toggle('open');
            }
            
  }
```

```css
.description {
      display: none;
  }
  .description.open {
      display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div>
        <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
        <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
<div>
        <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
        <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
<div>
        <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
        <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the listener, check the argument to get the event, which points you to the button that was clicked. Then, you can reassign that button's text, and navigate to its `nextElementSibling` to get to its adjacent `.description` element:

```js
var toggleInnerHTML = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleBtn");
var desc = document.querySelectorAll('.description');


for (i = 0; i < toggleInnerHTML.length; i++) {
  toggleInnerHTML[i].addEventListener('click', toggleText);
}

function toggleText(e) {
  e.target.textContent = e.target.textContent === '+' ? '-' : '+';
  e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open');

}
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}

.description.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
  <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
  <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
  <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

classList.toggle return a Boolean value, so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".toggleBtn").forEach(bt=>
  {
  bt.onclick=_=>{
    bt.textContent = bt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open') ? '-' : '+'
    } 
  })
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}
.description.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
  <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
  <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="toggleBtn">+</button>
  <div class="description">Text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `onclick='functiontocall()` inside your html

for example

```
<button class="toggleBtn" onclick='Showtext('description1')'>+</button>
```

and JS

```
function Showtext(textclass){
      document.getElementsByClassName(textclass).display = "block";
}
```

but you should change description divs to `description1` and `description2` and `description3`

in this case you can specify your buttons

i hope it be useful for you